# compare/merge two ms access databases

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got two ms access .mdb files that I need to compare/merge. Any good tools out there for this? Any way to easily export both to ascii sql where I can use something like Beyond Compare?

Comment: did you google your question?

Comment: yes, of course. and I used to have a decent, free one, but don't remember what it was called. When I googled for it all I was finding were crappy looking non-free ones. hence coming here to look for a rec.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the EXPORT command on the File menu to send data to data files. Alternatively, I think there is a Right-Click export option.

If you have a lot of tables, you can do this in VBA for Access as well. OTTOMH

```
Dim DB as Database
Dim Tbl as TableDef
Dim i as Integer
SET DB = CURRENTDB

For i = 0 to DB.TableDefs.Count -1
    Set Tbl = Db.TableDef (i)
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport Tbl, "C:\Temp\" + Tbl.Name + ".CSV", ExportSpec
Next Tbl
```

Comment: yeah, that's one table at a time. And I'm not going to SQL Server, which I don't have. I was hoping to avoid writing code to do this...

Comment: oh, I see where the confusion might have come from: when I wrote "export to .sql" I meant to a plain text sql file, not sql server. I'll edit for clarity...

Comment: also the tag, I suppose. Obviously, I meant SQL the language, not SQL the server....